# UITableViewCell optional image

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

Good evening! I work with table which shows user posts. User can write text and post it. Also he can attach some photo to his post with text, or just post photo without text. So my table view cell has to dynamically add/remove text labels and image view and resize to fit them. I know there is smth with auto-layouts, but I can't find a proper guide for my purposes. Any advices or simple examples?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: @H4Hugo in a nutshell, I need to resize my table view cell according to it's content. If there is only an image, I need a cell with just an image, if there is only text, it must be a small cell with just text in it. Obviously, if there are both, cell must contain an image with text written below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have dynamic sizing table view cell's and you are using Auto Layout you could use something like:

`tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Just add that line in where you set your delegate and data source for the UITableView